# Is there a way to make a Dynamic UI with Images of RShiny load faster?

Tags: r, shiny, dynamic-ui

I have a dynamic UI that loads a **card item and its description**, and for 1 page I make a 50 cards displayed (as default) or else the remainder of the cards in last page (which is defined from `num_cards()` reactive values) this is the dynamic UI code:

```
output$dynamicUI <- renderUI({
    do.call(tagList, lapply(1:num_cards(), function(i) {
        fluidRow(
          column(width = 3,
                 style = "padding: 0; margin: 0;",  # Zero margin and padding
                 box(
                   uiOutput(paste0("dynamicImage", i))
                 )
          ),
          column(width = 9,
                 style = "padding: 0; margin: 0;",  # Zero margin and padding
                 fluidRow(
                   # Row 1 (top)
                   column(width = 9,
                          style = "padding: 0; margin: 0; font-size: 36px; font-family: 'Berlin Sans FB', Demi; background: transparent;",  # Zero margin and padding
                          box(
                            width = 12,
                            textOutput(paste0("cardName", i))
                          )
                   ),
                   column(width = 3,
                          style = "padding: 0; margin: 0; font-alignment: 'right'; font-size: 18px; font-family: 'Times New Roman', serif; background: transparent; text-align: right !important;",  # Zero margin and padding
                          box(
                            width = 10,
                            textOutput(paste0("releaseDate", i))
                          )
                   )
                 ),
                 fluidRow(class = "custom-fluid-row",
                          # Row 2 (middle)
                          column(
                            width = 2,
                            div(
                              imageOutput(paste0("BOXICONONE", i)) %>% tagAppendAttributes(class = 'BOXICONONE'),
                              div(
                                textOutput(paste0("BOXONE", i)) %>% tagAppendAttributes(class = 'BOXONE')
                              )
                            )
                          ),
                          column(
                            width = 2,
                            div(
                              imageOutput(paste0("BOXICONTWO", i)) %>% tagAppendAttributes(class = 'BOXICONTWO'),
                              div(
                                textOutput(paste0("BOXTWO", i)) %>% tagAppendAttributes(class = 'BOXTWO')
                              )
                            )
                          ),
                          column(
                            width = 2,
                            div(
                              imageOutput(paste0("BOXICONTHREE", i)) %>% tagAppendAttributes(class = 'BOXICONTHREE'),
                              div(
                                textOutput(paste0("BOXTHREE", i)) %>% tagAppendAttributes(class = 'BOXTHREE')
                              )
                            )
                          ),
                          column(
                            width = 2,
                            style = "padding: 0; margin: 0; font-size: 22px; font-family: 'Times New Roman', serif; background: transparent",  # Zero margin and padding
                            box(
                              width = 12,
                              textOutput(paste0("BOXFOUR", i)) %>% tagAppendAttributes(class = 'BOXFOUR')
                            )
                          ),
                          column(
                            width = 2,
                            style = "padding: 0; margin: 0; font-size: 22px; font-family: 'Times New Roman', serif; background: transparent",  # Zero margin and padding
                            box(
                              width = 12,
                              textOutput(paste0("BOXFIVE", i)) %>% tagAppendAttributes(class = 'BOXFIVE')
                            )
                          )
                 ),
                 fluidRow(class = "custom-fluid-row",
                          # Row 3 (bottom)
                          column(
                            height = 130,
                            width = 12,
                            style = "padding: 0; margin: 0; background: transparent; font-size: 18px; font-family: 'Times New Roman'",  # Zero margin and padding
                            box(
                              height = 130,
                              width = 12,
                              textOutput(paste0("cardDescription", i))
                            )
                          )
                 )
          )
        )
      }))
  })
```

Above are the main UI in my apps, and I have left sidebarmenu that when clicked, updates the dynamicUI accordingly to the menu category, but the loading for this UI is kinda slow, (I think because I use a lots of image displayed as the card image and its box icons). Here is the profvis results of some simulation

[image]

I was wondering if theres a way I can make the UI smoother or maybe make the renderUI/renderImage load image more faster.. I appreciate your help!

EDIT: These are the minimal reproducible example for the apps that i can create, I can`t make it more simpler than this, feel free to use

https://sendeyo.com/en/065bf146a6

Comment: I don't have a direct answer for this, but in my experience: drop a few `cat()` or `message()` calls in your function to check how many times the UIoutput is evaluated, as sometimes Shiny reactives "blink" many times before finally rendering correctly, and these unnecessary renderings can be avoided using `req()` or waiting for conditions to meet before rendering. Also, maybe try splitting up `renderUI()` into smaller elements.

Comment: I see, I just know that `req()` can be useful for this, thanks for sharing! @BastiánOleaHerrera,

Comment: I'd suggest to use `tags$img(...)` along with `lapply` instead of nesting `uiOutput` in `renderUI`. Please consider posting a [reproducible example](https://mastering-shiny.org/action-workflow.html#getting-help).

Comment: @ismirsehregal i will try, I am making a minimal example for this one

Comment: [Here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/is-there-a-way-to-make-a-dynamic-ui-with-images-of-rshiny-load-faster/178839/2) a posit community crosspost can be found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not willing to download from sendeyo...
what is the slow or data heavy part of your cards ?
is it image data ?
the html standard includes a lazy load feature.
Heres an example of 1000 lady loaded images thrown into a dynamic shiny ui. it seems highly performant.
There is definitely a dip in perceived performance when removing the lazy option, but its still rather fast even without ...

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(glue)
ui <- fluidPage(
  uiOutput("dynimages")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$dynimages <- renderUI({
    
    tagList(map(1:1000,
        \(x){tags$image( loading="lazy" ,
                         src=glue("https://picsum.photos/id/{x}/400/600"))}))
    
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: yes the images data, and also the sidebar category since I have a lots of sidebar menu, the observeEvent used to read changes on sidebarmenu also makes the UI slow..

Comment: these setups are quite fast.. in my code i actually use a 200% height and width for the each card size.. i will try to test your approach of lazy loading, thanks for sharing this!